# How to copy a generic Collection in Java using wildcards

Tags: java, generics

Consider this java class:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class NumberSet {

    private Collection<? extends Number> numbers;

    public NumberSet(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public NumberSet(NumberSet other) {

        //copy other.numbers to this.numbers
        numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Iterator<? extends Number> it = other.numbers.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            numbers.add(it.next()); // Here's Syntax Error near `it.next()`
        }

    }
}
```

There is This Syntax Error inside `for` loop:

```
actual argument Number cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface Collection
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
```

I Understand the meaning of `PECS` but **I want to implement a copy-constructor** for this class. the copied instance would be used Just as an snapshot of `other`. any Idea?

Comment: @BrianAgnew I really don't understand how one can mark this question as a duplicate of `What is PECS`? If someone knew the term `PECS`, they wouldn't post a question in the first place.

Comment: I've re-opened it since I agree with you. I think the PECS question/answer does address this, but I take your point completely

Comment: @BrianAgnew Thanks for the reopening the question. I am editing the title so that it is more accessible.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I was not at my computer until now. Thanks all for participation. I knew the meaning of `PECS`, but The problem is still a mystery for me, I would change the question body, ASAP, to clear all ambiguities.

Comment: @MostafaNazari Wow, you just changed the entire question. Yet the solution remains the same. Use `? super` instead of `? extends`. At this point, I would like to ask you : If you have understood what `PECS` is and you know you are supposed to use `? super`, what is still a mystery? The linked answer on `PECS` explains why you can't put when using `? extends`

Comment: I have done this code, by doing this: use `LinkedList<Number> numbers = new LinkedList<>();` before `for` to hide generic collection `this.numbers`, and after copying finished, use `this.numbers = numbers;`. but I'm looking for better solution @ChetanKinger @BrianAgnew

Comment: I am voting to close this question as `unclear` since it's beyond me to comprehend what the OP is asking.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Using `? super` here is not possible. the problem is: how to make a copy of `Collection<? extends Number>` ?

Comment: @MostafaNazari If you are adamant about sicking to `? extends`, then you can't `add` elements to the `Collection<? extends Number>`. What you can simply do is assign `numbers=others`. If you don't want to do that, then open up the `JVM` sourcecode and modify it to allow addition using `? extends`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Change :

```
 Collection<? extends Number> dst
```

To :

```
 Collection<? super Number> dst
```

Addition is not allowed using `? extends`. There is something known as the `Get` and `Put` principle. Quoting from the [Generics and Collections](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zaoK0Z2STlkC&pg=PR7&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q=get%20and%20put&f=false) book from [Philip Wadler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Wadler) :

> The Get and Put Principle: use an extends wildcard when you only get
>   values out of a structure, use a super wildcard when you only put
>   values into a structure, and don’t use a wildcard when you both get
>   and put

Also take a look at [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for a more common explanation of this phenomenon. (However, I prefer the `GET` and `PUT` principle over the `Producer` and `Consumer` principle as it is less confusing)

Comment: See also the mnemonic PECS at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs .

Comment: @ChetanKinger - where did the above quote come from ? Can you provide a link or reference ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Added a link to the book.